# Call Cobol or C functions in Cobol program called by C# program

Tags: c#, dll, window, cobol

I work on a simple console application in **C#** 4.6.1.
I can make cobol program using *Micro Focus* environnent.
My goal is to call, from console application, cobol program which have calls to another cobol program.

Today I can call with success cobol methods in cobol dll file, using **DllImport** or **LoadLibrary**.

In my example, my cobol method named **Hello**, in dll file **hello.dll**, print *"Hello :D"* and in the same way, my another cobol program named **Itsme**, in dll file **itsme.dll**, print *"It's me"*.

Inside Cobol program, we can call another program with his name. In my example, I add the the following line in my **Hello** program :

```
CALL "ITSME"
```

In my console application, I load both dll file (hello.dll and itsme.dll).
When I call my method **Hello**, it's supposed to print *"Hello It's me"*.
But it won't, because of :

> Load error : file 'Itsme'
>
> error code: 173, pc=0, call=1, seg=0 173
> Called program file not found in drive/directory

I know it work on Unix system, using **dlopen** instead of **LoadLibrary**.
**LoadLibrary** isn't the equivalent of **dlopen** ?

EDIT : There is a little sample of code after looking to Simon Sobisch answer :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "cobtypes.h"

typedef int(__stdcall *f_cobinit)();
typedef cobrtncode_t(__stdcall *f_cobcall)(const cobchar_t *callname, int argcnt, cobchar_t **argvec);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE dll1 = LoadLibrary("CobolDlls.dll");
    HINSTANCE dll2 = LoadLibrary("CobolDlls2.dll");
    HINSTANCE dllCbl = LoadLibrary("cblrtsm.dll");

    printf("cobinit : ");
    f_cobinit init = (f_cobinit)GetProcAddress(dllCbl, "cobinit");
    printf("%d", init());

    f_cobcall hi = (f_cobcall)GetProcAddress(dllCbl, "cobcall");
    cobrtncode_t c = hi((cobchar_t*)"P2", 0, NULL);
    
    getchar();
}
```

I successfully load librairies, and my call to **cobinit** is working (result : 0).
But when I call **cobcall** method, I have the error code 173 seen previously.

I precise that "P2" is refering to a cobol program named "P2" included in "CobolDlls.dll", which is build as a shared single dynmic library with MicroFocus, and all Dlls are in the same directory than the console application.

P2 program :

```
   identification division.
   program-id. P2.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   local-storage section.
   procedure division.
   display "Hello I'm P2"
   goback.
```

Thanks for your help,
Yoann

Comment: please drop a short note in the answer's comments if this worked and/or what you had to change, allowing me to update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The point is to remove all instances of `LoadLibrary` for the COBOL moules. The `cobcall` is the function that has to do the call.
I've adjusted my answer (even if this is more "guessing" [with only having the MF docs at hand...])

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your edited answer work well and help me a lot :D I did not know that I have to "preload" cobol dll in this way. When I preload my dll, one program inside this dll is executed, like the dll main entry. I don't know it's because of a MicroFocus configuration or a cobol code. I'll check it. Thanks again.

Comment: A question: Do you know how COBOL could call C#? This is possibly the opposite of your question, but I was wondering how can this be done. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I only worked 6 months on this topic, and that was three years ago, I don't remember much.

I think we can call C # DLL libraries with COBOL, maybe these links could help you.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/RSM50/cobol-calling-C-Sharp/

https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Net-Express-Server-Express-Forum/cobol-call-to-c/td-p/1733280

Sorry,
Yoann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is a *guess* as I did not tested it, but for most COBOL implementations there is a a runtime library (which should be the target for `dlopen` / `LoadLibrary`) which provides functions to use it.

A quick search in the Micro Focus documentation showed [C Functions for Calling COBOL](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/GUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784/HRCCRHCCAL00.html), you likely want to use [`cobinit()`, `cobcall()` and `cobtidy()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/GUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784/HRCCRHCCAL10.html).

As everything concerning the COBOL parts is done by the runtime library (which needs to be either linked or loaded itself) you'll need to set options like where to find the modules and other possibly relevant settings **before the call to `cobinit()`**.

One setting possibly needed:
`COBPATH` - If the COBOL modules do not reside in the **process' current directory** - set the same way you'd set PATH variable (entries separated by ";" on Windows)

I'd try something like the following in this case (in C#, the sample was C++)

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("COBPATH", "X:\path;Y:\other-path");
```

According to the documentation about [Calling Programs](https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx51/prcall.htm) combined programs are loaded by loading the library containing them first with a plain `CALL`. Your adjusted program would then look like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "cobtypes.h"

typedef int(__stdcall *f_cobinit)();
typedef cobrtncode_t(__stdcall *f_cobcall)(const cobchar_t *callname, int argcnt, cobchar_t **argvec);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE dllCbl = NULL;

    f_cobinit cobInit = NULL;
    f_cobcall cobCall = NULL;

    int retCode;

    printf("load COBOL runtime : ");
    HINSTANCE dllCbl = LoadLibrary("cblrtsm.dll");
    if (!dllCbl) {
        retCode = (int)GetLastError();
        printf("failure: %d\n", retCode);
        return retCode;
    }
    puts("success");

    printf("lookup COBOL functions : ");
    cobInit = (f_cobinit)GetProcAddress(dllCbl, "cobinit");
    cobCall = (f_cobcall)GetProcAddress(dllCbl, "cobcall");
    printf("init: %p, call: %p - ", (void *)cobInit, (void *)cobCall);
    if (!cobInit || !cobCall) {
        retCode = (int)GetLastError();
        printf("failure: %d\n", retCode);
        return retCode;
    }
    puts("success");


    printf("cobinit : ");
    retCode = cobInit();
    if (retCode) {
        printf("failure: %d\n", retCode);
        return retCode;
    }
    puts("success");

    printf("preload CobolDlls : ");
    retCode = cobCall((cobchar_t*)"CobolDlls", 0, NULL);
    puts("success");

    //printf("preload CobolDlls2 : ");
    //retCode = cobCall((cobchar_t*)"CobolDlls2", 0, NULL);
    //puts("success");

    printf("do actual CALL "P2" : ");
    retCode = cobCall((cobchar_t*)"P2", 0, NULL);
    printf("returned with: %d\n", retCode);

    getchar();
}
```

Note: Be aware that the COBOL runtime may issue an `exit` (especially when there are errors in the COBOL parts or a module does `STOP RUN`). You want to make sure to be able to catch it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will look for these C functions. Speaking of exit or stop run, how can I catch it ? Because in my test, when there are errors in the COBOL parts, my application simply exit. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd start to `try {} catch(Exception e) {} catch () {}`, if this doesn't help you'd have to check if the runtime library allows you to register and exit handler (normally a COBOL and/or C pointer to a function) *and* the exit handler can itself tidy the runtime library up - if yes you *may* get back to your managed program.
In general "talk to the vendor" may help.

Comment: You also can try to migrate your COBOL source (if available) to GnuCOBOL and add code into its runtime "libcob" to never exit to the OS but return back to the caller :-)

Comment: Unfortunatly, the classic try catch don't work. I will look for this exit handler if exist. I have to work on windows system, I don't think that GnoCobol work on it :D Thank you very much.

Comment: Quoting http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/gnucobol:
"GnuCOBOL works on various platforms, including GNU/Linux, Unix, Mac OS X, and Microsoft Windows. GnuCOBOL has also been built on HP/UX, z/OS, SPARC, RS6000, AS/400, along with other combinations of machines and operating systems." :-)

Comment: Note: I'd still leave the classic try catch in as the RTS may raise a signal itself - in this case the catch block should be performed.

Comment: Unfortunatly I have to work with MicroFocus. Thanks for your reply.